# gap:["Device","getDeviceInfo","Device1231860141"] error on PhoneGap

Tags: android, cordova

I have created a `phonegap` app and I added Android platform to it. But unfortunately, `deviceready` event is not getting fired. It works fine on ripple emulator but it is not working on chrome (desktop) and on the android phone as well.

If I run it on chrome (desktop) or my Android L phone, I get the error gap:

> ["Device","getDeviceInfo","Device1231860141"]

and the browser as well as NetBeans hangs.

I have the `cordova.js` file in my `www` folder. I tried removing it, and the error goes away, but `deviceready` is still not fired.

The following is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320, user-scalable=no" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/libs/jquery.mobile-1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function init(){
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);
}
 function onDeviceReady() {
    startWatch();
}

// Start watching the acceleration
//
function startWatch() {

    // Update acceleration every 3 seconds
    var options = { frequency: 3000 };

    watchID = navigator.accelerometer.watchAcceleration(onSuccess, onError, options);
}

// Stop watching the acceleration
//
function stopWatch() {
    if (watchID) {
        navigator.accelerometer.clearWatch(watchID);
        watchID = null;
    }
}

// onSuccess: Get a snapshot of the current acceleration
//
function onSuccess(acceleration) {
    var element = document.getElementById('accelerometer');
    element.innerHTML = 'Acceleration X: ' + acceleration.x         + '<br />' +
                        'Acceleration Y: ' + acceleration.y         + '<br />' +
                        'Acceleration Z: ' + acceleration.z         + '<br />' +
                        'Timestamp: '      + acceleration.timestamp + '<br />';
}

// onError: Failed to get the acceleration
//
function onError() {
    alert('onError!');
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**[deviceready](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#deviceready)** is a cordova event it will not work in browser.

```
...
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);
function onDeviceReady() {
    startWatch();
}

...
</script>
</head>
<body onload="onDeviceReady()">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: check if you cordova.js included in you current html